# Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

My Flutter is Working fine in debug mode when connected to a real device. But when building the apk it shows the following error. I tried running
`flutter pub get` and
`flutter pub upgrade` numerous time but to no effect.

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.2.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_sign_in-5.0.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlesignin\GoogleSignInPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_storage-8.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\storage\FlutterFirebaseStoragePlugin.java:38: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry 
has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry.Registrar registrar) { 
                                                ^
1 warning
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-1.2.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\auth\FlutterFirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.2.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.2.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I am creating this app which works perfectly debug mode when I connect my Phone as an emulator but when I build the APK it shows the above error even then after completion when I install the app on my phone there are some things that don't work. the main issue: [Orignal Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67821214/flutter-app-showing-grey-screen-when-no-firebase-snaphot-data-present-in-releas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For deprecation pop will occur every time you do a flutter clean and then build the project again. I'd suggest you use the latest versions of firebase and google sign.

If this helps i was using   google_sign_in: ^5.0.2 and other firebase dependencies were set to null

2. For the grey screen as you said the app was able to run when you removed the image from your code. My assumption is it was not able to load the image from the folder structure or it was able to load the image but it had some renderoverflow issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest don't specify the version for firebase_core and google_sign_in in pubspec.yaml file.

Just added them in your file like
firebase_core:
google_sign_in:

run flutter clean and build the project again

Comment: Tried doing that but didn't work, the error stopped but my apps still shows grey screen when there is no data

Comment: Can you please share the code? Because i tried to run it with and without version assignment and it is working properly

Comment: GitHub: https://github.com/pranjalchaplot/masterpass

Comment: Can't run because the google-service.json file is missing

Comment: I have the google service.json I have just git ignored it.

Comment: Yep, i saw that in your git, either way are you still stuck at that issue? or is there any new update on it?

Comment: I'm sure the solution to your error will be in debug console. What does your debug console shows when you get that grey screen instead of password list?

Comment: I don't get this issue in debug mode everything is fine but when I build the APK and install it in my phone I then get this error so there is no way to see the debug console

Comment: So the app works fine when you run it in your emulator? but gives the blank screen in actual device?

Comment: I don't use emulator but my actual device connected with USB Tethering to flutter run and every time I run it, it builds debug mode apk which runs without any error but I can't work with that because it's in debug mode and hence quite slow but when I run flutter build --apk release mode or any other the above error occurs and also when I run the installed application it shows grey screen when loading and there is not firebase data which I have created a screen for (when no data is available) but works only in debug mode

Comment: I added some reference image in the original question you check that out to get a better understanding of what is the desired behaviour

Comment: Okay, let's try few things. First can you remove this patch from your code and check if just the text is displayed on the screen when you run the program in release mode Positioned(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/add_files_password_screen.png",
                        width: size.width * 0.55,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.04),

Comment: I added a generic answer.  Glad it worked . Congrats